# regex remove hyphens at start ,in between and start & end of the words

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have few documents which have text with hyphen at the start of the word, in between the words and at the start and end of the word.
I need help with regex to remove the hyphens for these 3 scenarios

sample text : ease singapore-based -fis -sgfis- fatca"

I tried the following regex

re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', "ease singapore-based fis -sgfis- fatca" but it removes all hypens.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

```
re.sub(r'-\b|\b-', ' ', "ease singapore-based fis -sgfis- fatca")
# trim multiple spaces here
```

Expression 1:

```
"-\b|\b-"
```

`\b` as of word Dividing line

[image]

or
Solution 2

```
re.sub(r'\s-\b|\b-\s', ' ', "ease singapore-based fis -sgfis- fatca")
```

Expression 2:

```
"\s-\b|\b-\s"
```

\s as of whitespace char

[image]

If you need to "singapore-based" to become "singapore based" use solution 2 and combine it with `\b-\b`:

so you will end up with `(\b-\b)|(\s-\b|\b-\s)`

Solution 3:

```
re.sub(r'(\b-\b)|(\s-\b|\b-\s)', ' ', "ease singapore-based fis -sgfis- fatca")
# no space trimming required
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```py
inp = "ease singapore-based -fis -sgfis- fatca"
output = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)-|-(?=\w)', '', inp)
print(output)  # ease singaporebased fis sgfis fatca
```

The regex used above says to match:

```regex
(?<=\w)-  match a hyphen preceded by a word character
|         OR
-(?=\w)   match a hyphen followed by a word character
```

Then, we replace such matching hyphens with empty string, to remove them.

Comment: How can i do this in 3 steps 1- Remove hyphens only from the start of the word 2. remove hyphens in between the word 3 remove hyphens from stat and end of the word.